# Java - Is there a way that I can use sin(x) instead of Math.sin(x) (for user input)?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I want to make a program where the user can enter "sin(x)" and the computer will treat it as "Math.sin(x)".  Is there some way I can do this? 
ps. I tried import static java.lang.Math.*; and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide example code - it looks like you need dynamic code evaluation; which Java does not support as it is a compiled language.

Comment: maybe define a function `double sin(double x) {return Math.sin(x)};`

Comment: And figure out if your problem is evaluating user input (as in the duplicate, and "for user input" implies), or evaluating `sin(x)` in that user input (which the rest of your question suggests).